# Listbox and control of items to display

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I tell them what I tried. I have a listbox that is bound by a property MVVM pattern ObservableCollection<>, where you get all the items, about 50 elements.

He set the dimensions of the Listbox to show only the first 10 items and I am trying to do now is display the following 10 items using a next  button, all without using the scrollbar of the listbox.

I need two buttons, next and back, which will showcase items of 10 to 10.

How to do it?.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

The silverlight toolkit contains a paging control. That sounds what you need.